# Does Feeblemind's saving throw use the original or current intelligence of the target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Feeblemind can, on a failed save, reduce a creature's intelligence and charisma to 1. That's a -5 modifier.

Every 30 days, the target can repeat this save. Does the character save with their current intelligence or their original? For a character with a DC spell save of 16, the character might never recover on their own without proficiency in intelligence saving throws. (Thanks to Michał Politowski for pointing out that nat 20's are not automatic successes on saving throws).

I guess the root of my question is that this seems over powered, but I really just want to make sure I'd be rolling the correct modifiers.

Comment: Be careful with words like "average" for non-symmetric distributions. Yes, the mean is 20 but the median is 14, that is, 50% of people will be feebleminded for 14 months or less and 50% for 15 or more.

Comment: Natural 20 is not an automatic success on a saving throw, so it's even worse for DC above 15.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski Get a cleric to cast a bless before making the save and boost the roll. :-)  Have a Bard apply one of his inspirations.

Comment: @MichałPolitowski Oh really? I guess I was mistaken

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the creature's stats (i.e. of it's new form).  Also, even an extremely long expected duration isn't likely to be considered 'overpowered' by the game developers; for comparison the spell used to be permanent.  Consider that the spell is a high-level single target spell effect that allows a save.

Comment: Permanent?  That is at least partly incorrect.  In its original form it could be removed by Dispel Magic. Ref Men and Magic, p. 30. "...it causes the recipient to
become feeble-minded until the spell is countered with a Dispell Magic."  In 1e, a Heal, Restoration, or Wish spell was required.  (PHB. p. 62). Recommend your revise your answer.

Comment: Note that if you compare the «Feeblemind» spell to other *more permanent* spells like «Disintegration» or «Death Ray»... «Feeblemind» is not that bad!

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Recommend you revise your definition of permanent.